# Is the squared difference between a $L^{2}$-function and a Non-$L^{2}$-function in $L^{2}$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space. Furthermore, let $Y,V : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be random vectors and let

$$ \int_{\Omega}{\vert \vert Y \vert \vert ^2}dP < \infty$$
and
$$ \int_{\Omega}{\vert \vert V \vert \vert ^2}dP = \infty.$$ Is it true that this implies

$$ \int_{\Omega}{\vert \vert V-Y \vert \vert ^2}dP = \infty?$$

It seems intuitive, but I have a hard time showing it rigorously.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The use of $\| \cdot \|$ is weird. I would use $\left| \cdot \right|$ instead.

Comment: I used $\lVert . \rVert$ since the exercise is about random vectors and not scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\|V\| \leq \|V-Y\| + \|Y\|$ (by the triangle inequality) and so
$$\int \|V\|^2 \leq \int (\|V-Y\| + \|Y\|)^2 \leq 4 \int \|V-Y\|^2 + \|Y\|^2$$
so if $\int \|V-Y\|^2 < \infty$ then $\int \|V\|^2 < \infty$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate on the second inequality?

Comment: Because I feel the leading factor should be 2 and not 4.

Comment: @Joker123 yeah, it works with $2$. I just stuck the inefficient bound you get by writing $(a+b)^2 \leq (2 \max(a,b))^2 \leq 4 (a^2+b^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!